# facebook 'like' button for facebook page but with callback

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-social-plugins

I want to use the facebook like button for a facebook fan page, but with a callback function.

So far I've only managed to get the callback function to work with a facebook app with the following code-

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script>
    FB.init({
        appId  : 'appID',
        status : true, // check login status
        cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml  : true, // parse XFBML
        channelUrl : 'http://www.my_url.com/channel.html', // channel.html file
        oauth  : true // enable OAuth 2.0
    });
</script>

<script>(function(d, s, id) {
   var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
   if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
   js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
   js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1";
   fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(href, widget) {
    callbackFunction();
});
</script>
```

Like I said, the above code works fine for a facebook app. But what I really want to do is bind code similar to this, but to a facebook page 'like' button such as the following-

```
<div class="fb-like-box" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/{page-name}" data-width="292" data-height="250"  data-show-faces="true" data-stream="true" data-header="true"></div>
```

Does anyone know of a way to achieve this?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I don’t know if I remember that correctly, but I think I’ve read or heard somewhere that this only works if you’re using the XFBML version of the like button – so maybe give that a try. (That definitively works, I’ve just used it recently.)

Comment: Thanks for that. I was stuck on this for a while, but switching to the XFBML version of the like button allowed the callback to work. Cheers again - if you wanted to paste your comment into an answer, I'd happily accept it as the answer :-)

Comment: @user1104955, using the `HTML5` version is the same as using `XFBML`, events will be triggered, only `iframe` version missing those events.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had capture a click on the laik of `<div class = "fb-like-box"` ... html5 diva.
Variant:

```
FB.Event.subscribe ('edge.create', function (response) {
     alert ('You just liked' + response);
});
```

You can only use in version XFBML of the like button,

but I had a very, and has decided in the end this variant

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>

<script>
     window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
 FB.init({appId: 'YOUR_FACEBOOK_APP_ID', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});
 FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) {
 alert('You just liked '+response);
 });
};
(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/ru_RU/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=265929413447804";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

</script>

<div class="fbp-one" style="margin-top: 62px;
                                margin-left: 60px;
                                position: absolute;
                                z-index: 1000;
                                height: 27px;
                                background-color: white;">
            <div class="fb-like" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="100" data-height="200" data-show-faces="false"></div>
</div>
<div class="fbp-two" style="position:relative;">
            <div class="fb-like-box" data-href="YOUR_ADRESS" data-width="190" data-show-faces="true" data-stream="false" data-header="true"></div>
</div>
```

Div 'FBP-one' getting better on the button in the FBP-two above and looks like one unit and functional works in all browsers, just paint CSS, each for himself :)

Answer (score 1):

In fact [Like Box](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/) behave the same as the [Like Button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) as for events fired, meaning that your code should work as expected. Here is the [working sample on fbrell](http://www.fbrell.com/saved/656b756adc415ff7056cf6a10c7e5b64).

Actually there is a problem with your code <strike>that may lead to unexpected behaviour</strike>, you have **two** versions of JS-SDK included on page, one as regular `script` tag (with `en_US` locale) and one included in asynchronous manner (with `en_GB` locale), you should use only one!

Beware that if you choose the second (async) version you need to define `window.fbAsyncInit` function and call your `FB.init` and `FB.subscribe` from there...

Comment: I removed one of the versions and the callback still didn't fire. If the HTML5 version works as well, is there anything else in my code that you can see is wrong. Although please note that the XFBML version of the code is working for me now.

Comment: You can see in the live sample I've provided that those callbacks are fired perfectly for like box code you've used in your question with `HTML5` version.